# UICollectionview reorder image cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I got a `UICollectionview` with XX images/cells and i want to make them swap places when dragging and dropping. I'm using the build-in reorder function  but its not fulfilling my needs. Here is the code:

```
longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture))
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.2
        longPressGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true

        cameraRollCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        switch(gesture.state) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = cameraRollCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: cameraRollCollectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            cameraRollCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
            cameraRollCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
            cameraRollCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            cameraRollCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
```

I basically just want the animation to only swap the moving cell and destination cell, not reordering the "neighbours" like the attached image.

[image: reorder default]

I have it working in "the behind" with this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                        to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {


        let temp = selectedUIImages[sourceIndexPath.row]
        selectedUIImages[sourceIndexPath.row] = selectedUIImages[destinationIndexPath.row]
        selectedUIImages[destinationIndexPath.row] = temp
 }
```

Comment: Is a collection view really the best way here? I ask, because I have an app that behaves in exactly the way you want (drag a square and drop on another square to swap them), but I don't use a collection view; it's just a grid of views. I don't need any of the stuff a collection view offers.

Comment: If you interested in using library, check this: https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout

Answer (score 0):

You could create a copy of the collectionViewCell's contentView when you recognize a long press upon a cell. Then you can make that copy move around with the touch (touchesMoved) while all the cells are still and when the user drops it (touchesEnded) you can calculate the indexPath for that location. When you have the indexPath, you can change the positions like you're already doing.